# Invoking Banach fixed-point theorem in space with fixed points at boundary

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

The setup of my problem is as follows.  I have a mapping $f:X \rightarrow X$ where $X$ is a general space that may be changed through adjusting a set of parameters that define it.  $f$ is always a contraction mapping over $X$, regardless of the parameters we use to define $X$.

For almost all parameter choices that define $X$, sequential composition of $f$ will converge to a fixed point in the interior of $X$ for any initial point.  However, in cases of ambiguity, for a subset of parameter choices, iteration of $f$ over any initial point in $X$ will converge to the boundary of $X$, which is always a fixed point.

I am mostly concerned with the first case where application of $f$ converges to a fixed point in the interior of $X$, so our entire space is just the interior of $X$ without the boundary.  Is there some specific way I should go about studying such a system?  How can I deal with the edge cases when the the parameters defining $X$ are such that the map converges to the boundary of the closure of $X$?

Example: Consider the real interval $(0, a)$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$, and let $f$ be a contraction mapping over this interval.  Then, if $a$ is a positive integer, for any point $x \in (0, a)$, $f^k(x) \rightarrow a$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.  However if $a \in \mathbb{R}^+ \setminus \mathbb{N}^+$, then for any point $x \in (0, a)$, $f^k(x) \rightarrow b$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, where $b \in (0, a)$.  As has been pointed out in the comments, such an interval $(0, a)$ is incomplete, and thus the Banach fixed point theorem cannot be used.  So then how can I prove that such a map will converge to a fixed point?  What if instead we took $[0, a]$ which is complete, and let $f(a), f(0)$ be undefined?

Comment: In your case, the mapping cannot be a contraction.

Comment: @HansEngler I see, however it would be a contraction over the interior of $X$ no?

Comment: @GEG The contraction mapping principle states that a contraction mapping on a *complete* metric space has a unique fixed point.  If you exclude the boundary, your space is no longer complete, and so the theorem does not apply.

Comment: @XanderHenderson If instead we defined $f$ over the interior of $X$, and do not allow for cases of ambiguity when $f$ converges to the boundary so instead it converges to a fixed point on the interior of $X$, then could the space be considered complete?

Comment: No.  The term "complete" has a very precise meaning, and we can't just "consider" a space to be complete.  If you exclude the boundary, then there will be Cauchy sequences which converge to boundary points, which you are excluding.  Thus the space will not be complete.

Comment: Define your mapping $f$ and your space $X$ in a new posting and reframe your question, then we'll all be able to comment.

Comment: @HansEngler Or, better yet, edit the current question to clarify.

Comment: Ok @XanderHenderson and Hans Engler, I have rewritten the above question, please let me know if I need to elucidate anything else.

Comment: You must have a concrete example in mind.  Please explain that example.

Comment: What Hans and Xander mean is that the proof of Banach's thm constructs a Cauchy sequence based on the contraction mapping inequality starting from an arbitrary point, and then uses completeness of the space to conclude that a limit must exist. If you only consider the interior of your space, it is no longer complete, and you only have a Cauchy sequence with potentially no limit in $\text{int}X$. If that "works" for you, then knock yourself out, but it does not prove existence of a fixed point, only a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I added a concrete example that very well demonstrates the kind of system I am dealing with.  The question, then, is how can I classify the dynamics of such a system if not with the contraction mapping theorem?

Comment: @Renard I added an example to the question.  In such a system, if $a$ was not a positive integer, could we call the metric space complete and invoke Banach's Theorem?